# SQL tables Identity seed property changes without apparent reason

Tags: .net, database, sql-server-2012, identity

I have a program in which I have two copies of the same database at two different places. In both database, uses can add new entry to some of the tables and at the end of the day, the databases are synchronised using a custom application that does the sync. In order to make sure that IDS do not cross each other ever, the first database IDS starts at 1 and the other database starts at 1000000.

For some reasons, it seems that the database which ID starts at 1 sometime shift to 1000000 so when the user create a new entry after a sync, a primary key violation is sent and the program stop working.

For many reasons, I cannot do a "simple sync"

I tried to "Reseed" the tables after each sync using the following code in order to prevent the problem, but it seems to happens even with this.

```
DECLARE @MaxIdSuivi bigint
SELECT @MaxIDSuivi = max(id) from t_Suivis  where id < 1000000
SET @MaxIDSuivi = ISNULL(@MaxIDSuivi,0)
DBCC CHECKIDENT (t_Suivis, reseed, @MaxIDSuivi)
```

When I do it manually, I can see that the old ID was really set to above the 1000 000 mark, which doesn't make any sens to me.

Does anyone knows what could be causing this problem?

Update : I tried to add a new entry in the table AFTER doing a manual reseed and it seem I can recreate the problem. Could it be possible that the following code in TSQL causes the problem ?

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT T_Suivis ON
```

I set it OFF after but, could that be the cause ?

Edit : After some tests, I found out that if I insert an ID in a table that is higher than the current seed, the seed is automatically modified to fit the next ID after that one I just inserted. If I entereed 1000 002 for exemple, the seed is changed to 1000002 so the next id will be 1000003, which in my case is completly wrong. Is there any way to prevent that from happining, either from some configuration in the server or option in TSQL ?

This is causing major problem in our system right now.

Comment: The problem is likely in your custom application, not the DB.

Comment: What does DBCC CHECKIDENT (T_Suivis, NORESEED) report after the reseed?

Comment: To answer your edit - why don't you use your reseed code after every insert above 1000000. I thought that's what you were doing.

Comment: The IDENTITY system in SQL Server is horribly misdesigned for all but the most basic cases. Expect problems. Use `SEQUENCE` instead.

Comment: @Bob : You are right, yet on some occasion it was not the case, which explains the problem. I will fix it so that it do it evertime. As for Usr, I am not aware of the sequence. I will check that for future projetcts